# How to kill sound from a macos app (iOS simulator)

Tags: macos, xcode-simulator

How to revoke a permission for a macos app (iOS simulator) to make any utterances to any audio devices whatsoever?
I have a sw keyboard giving some unsolicited feedback sounds unwated.

In menu -> I/O -> Audio Output apparently there is an audio output device selection. But apparently there no "None" option :-[

Comment: macOS doesn't have 'sound permissions' nor does it have built-in per application volume levels. Something like [SoundSource](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/soundsource/) can handle per-app levels, but I think that's rather overkill for an app that beeps at you when you don't want it to… so I'm not going to add it as an answer ;)

Comment: To add insult to the injury it does not even bother to respect the sound output device selected in setting.

Comment: That probably depends on whether it considers it to be a 'system beep' or 'sound'. it's not an app I've ever used, so I'm completely guessing, btw ;)

Comment: It does not respect the os setting, it has an output device selection of its own: ive updated the questyion